# Javascript replace() regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am wondering how to get rid of periods, commas, and whitespace in one .replace() function. I have found many different things on it, but none have a example of how to stack a few different things into one. So if this has been answer I am sorry but I have been up for 13hrs working on one thing, and seem to suck at learning JavaScript. So this is just adding on. Anyway, any help would be appreciated... I am passing out now.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://regex101.com/ here is a regex playground

Comment: `[.,\s]` matches period, comma, and whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you're so tired and you're passing out, why bother with the regex.

```
var stringToCleanup = stringToCleanup
    .split('.').join('')
    .split(',').join('')
    .split(' ').join('');
```